# Error in Encoding android code using Proguard

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, proguard

I am using proguard to secure my android apk from reverse engineering.

But when I completed all the steps which is needed to on proguard tool in my app then it gives error like bellow:

```
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp] proguard.ParseException: Expecting type and name instead of just '***' before '(' in line 85 of file 'D:\Ranjana\New folder\DemoProApp\bin\proguard.txt',
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp]   included from argument number 6
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp]  at   `proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:857)
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:697)
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:139)
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp] '-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-03-11 10:55:04 - DemoProApp] operable program or batch file.`
```

And my Proguard-project.txt file is like bellow:

```
-keep class com.google.ads.** # Don't proguard AdMob classes
-dontwarn com.google.ads.** # Temporary workaround for v6.2.1. It gives a warning that    you can ignore
# Add any classes the interact with gson
-keep class com.example.Get_TargetTask
-keep class com.example.Get_Update_Task
-keep class com.example.GetAlertTask_CGM
-keep class com.example.GetAlertTask
-keep class com.example.GetApplicationDrawable
-keep class com.example.GetAssignedWorkTask
-keep class com.example.GetBarCode
-keep class com.example.GetRootTask
-keep class com.example.GetSignature

-keep class com.example.GetSmsTask
-keep class com.example.GuiNotificationActivity

-keep public class com.example.** {*;}
 ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
 -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
 -dump class_files.txt
 -printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
 -allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
 -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
 -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
static final long serialVersionUID;
private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
java.lang.Object writeReplace();
java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.


-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;
}  
# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
1. keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.example.** { *; }
-keep public class * {
 public protected *;
}
-keep class com.example.Assign_revert.java.** {
void set*(***);
void set*(int, ***);

boolean is*(); 
boolean is*(int);

*** get*();
*** get*(int);
}


-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields.   Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

2. List item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message refers to line 85 of file `proguard.txt` (not `proguard-project.txt`). That line appears to be missing a method name inbetween the return type (the wildcard `***`) and the opening parenthesis for the method arguments.

Note that the Android SDK nowadays contains a standard configuration file that already specifies all the generic Android configuration for you (with -printseeds, -keepattributes, etc).

Comment: progurad.txt is auto generated file within bin folder we can't modify anything in proguard.txt.

Comment: You're right. This is a bug in the aapt tool in the Android SDK, which generates the file. It seems to have a problem interpreting one of your resource files. You should try to figure out why it is creating the erroneous line in proguard.txt, and maybe work around it by adapting your resource file. There are a couple of similar reports here on Stack Overflow.